# Is the metric space of polynomial of degree $\leq1$ complete with the following metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I must determine if the following metric space is complete

> $$\mathbb R_1[x]\times \mathbb R_1[x]\rightarrow \mathbb R:  d(p(x),q(x))=max\{|p(0)-q(0)|,|p(1)-q(1)|\}$$
>   where
>   $$\mathbb R_1[x]=\{p(x)=(ax+b)| a,b \in \mathbb R   \}$$ is the subset of polynomials of degree $\leq 1$
>   Is $(\mathbb R_1[x],d) $complete?

my try:

Let $\{p(x)\}_n$ be a Cauchy sequence

by definition

$\forall \epsilon, \exists n_0, \forall n,m \geq n_0 $    $d(p_n(x),p_m(x))< \epsilon$

$$d(p_n(x),p_m(x))=max\{|p_n(0)-p_m(0)|,|p_n(1)-q_m(1)|\}$$
since the max should be greater than any  of the arguments:
$$|p_n(0)-p_m(0)|\leq max\{|p_n(0)-p_m(0)|,|p_n(1)-q_m(1)|\}<\epsilon$$ and
$$|p_n(1)-p_m(q)|\leq max\{|p_n(0)-p_m(0)|,|p_n(1)-q_m(1)|\}<\epsilon$$
so(I am not sure)
this implies that $p_n(1)=a_n$ 
and $p_n(0)=b_n$ are Cauchy sequences

Does this make sense?
At this part I am stuck, how does this help me(if it is correct) to conclude if the space is complete or not? I should show somehow the Cauchy sequence is convergent

Comment: thanks, i just fixed that typo

Comment: Your ideas are correct, though: $p_n(0)$ and $p_n(1)$ are Cauchy sequences, so they have limits $p(0)$ and $p(1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Hint: Does this give you a candidate for a limit of the $p_n$?

Comment: If the coefficients converge, so does to polynomial to the one with the limit coefficients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}(\mathbb R_1[x],d)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R^2\\p(x)&\mapsto&\bigl(p(0),p(1)\bigr).\end{array}$$It is a bijection and it becomes an isometry if we consider on $\mathbb R^2$ the metric $d_1$ defined by$$d_\infty\bigl((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\bigr)=\max\bigl\{\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert,\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert\bigr\}.$$But $(\mathbb R^2,d_\infty)$ is complete (in fact, $\mathbb R^n$ endowed with a metric induced from *any* norm is complete) and therefore $(\mathbb R_1[x],d)$ is complete too.